# Getting exim variable in perl script

Tags: perl, exim, exim4

My problem is with exim.conf where i try to set hostname using perl

In exim.conf

```
host = "${perl{func}{arg}}"
```

In exim.pl.local its accessing Exim variable from exim.conf in following way

```
my $phost   = Exim::expand_string('$primary_hostname');
```

However, the value is not getting evaluated and the value of **"$phost"** comes out to be literal as follow.

```
print $phost   //outputs ${perl{func}{arg}}.
```

Any way i can change the code in exim.conf or exim.pl.local to get the result of the subroutine?

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/exam.pl.local

```
sub getprimaryhost {
   my $phost   = Exim::expand_string('$primary_hostname');
   return $phost;
}
```

then in /etc/exim.conf

```
smtp_active_hostname = ${perl{'getprimaryhost'}}
```

smtp_active_hostname will be set to what ever the sub returns in the case above it will be the value of primary_hostname. Also this does not seem to work for primary_hostname.